# Entrypoint bash script is not executed in Docker

Tags: bash, docker, containers, entry-point

Following is my docker file.

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN mkdir /data
COPY . /data
WORKDIR /data
USER root
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/data/getString.sh"]
```

Following is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello World'
```

I build the docker file using the command:

```
docker build --no-cache -t test6:1
```

The command is executed successfully but in the end, I get the following message:

```
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

But I don't see the bash script getting executed anywhere.

How do I fix this?

Comment: [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: When I use docker run -t -d test6:1 , it returns a big number. But no where can I see the bash script getting executed.

Comment: Because you are not running it in a way where that is possible. Take out the `-d` option if you want to see the output. This is a common FAQ.